# QSqlQueryModel, QSqlDatabase not displaying data in tableview

Tags: python, pyside

This code works perfectly in linux but when testing on windows it will not display the query into  tableview. I get no errors in windows. Both systems are 32bit everything else works perfectly. when i click my button to display the query, linux fills table, windows just sits there. when printing getcwd() in code below it shows that i am in correct database directory.

```
def getdata():
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE3")
    db.setDatabaseName('ias2014.db')
    db.open()
    model = QSqlQueryModel()
    model.setQuery("select hdr,prof,clss, semester, form from header")
    w.tableView.setModel(model)
```

Comment: Can you execute some data() calls on the model to see if it is returning any data on windows at all?

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but how would i achieve this?

Comment: This is how the view works internally, by constructing a ModelIndex (i.e., row, column). I suppose the easiest would be to print model.rowCount() and model.columnCount(), which should only be filled in if there is a successful connection.

Comment: mdurant you are the best!! Row and column count sizes were zero.So changed from "QSQLITE3" to QSQLITE". For some reason in my windows setup "QSQLITE3" is not an available driver.  I thought i tried changing that last night but was running it on a 64bit windows install not 32, so not sure.

Comment: I will write a short answer, so that maybe your problem can be useful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I order to check if you have successfully established a connection to your database, you can query one of the fetch methods such as `model.rowCount()` and `model.columnCount()`. Also, you can attempt to access actual data in the database by calling, e.g.,  `data(model.createIndex(0,0) )`

When switching between installations and OSs, you may find that you are missing a driver to the particular database you are trying to use.

Comment: If you have a reference to the SQLITE issue, please edit my answer or post a comment.